# Difference between view.findViewById(R.id....) and just findViewById(R.id...)

Tags: android, android-view, findviewbyid

I'm trying to implement a Custom Array Adapter ,

Problem is my code crashes when I use

```
 ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

rather than

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

where rowView is the layout file for the ListView that i have infalted.

Why does this occur , I thought rowView.findViewById(R.id..) will just make it faster to find the element by id, but without it the app crashes, 
Can you please explain

This is my Activity code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Now for the list view

    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    String[] values =new String[]{"iOS","android","firefoxOs","Ubuntu"};

   MySimpleAdapter simpleAdapter=new MySimpleAdapter(this,values);

   listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    //

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class MySimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private Context context;
    private String[] values;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //listView calls this on its adapter for each row
        Log.v("list","getView");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);

        TextView textView1= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        textView1.setText(values[position]);
        //for the android row alone set an image , others leave it as blank
        if(values[position].startsWith("and"))
        {
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);//Ok R.drawale....is also an id
        }


        return rowView;
    }

    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context,String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_row,values);

        this.context=context;
        this.values=values;
        Log.v("list","constructor");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

findViewById always requires a context to find the view.

If you are calling this from a class which is extends the `Activity` class, you could just use `findViewById`, because Activity is the context.

When you are calling it from a class that extends `fragment`, you have to use `getActivity().findViewById`

In your case, since you are calling it in an `adapter`, you need to find that view within `listview row`. so you use `view.findViewById`

Comment: I edited the question now , can you please elaborate

Comment: Oh ok I get it ,since my Inner class does not extend an activity ,by default there is no this(context).findViewById(...) , so there lies the problem, am i correct?

Comment: But from what you are saying , why was there no IDE warning or a compile time error when I used findViewById without  a context and Btw My CustomAdapter class is an inner class of the Main Activity which extends activity ...can you explain?

Comment: yes, thats the problem. but i wonder how you could use findviewbyid in adapter without a compilation error.

Comment: I said it is an inner class , ill put the entire code now

Comment: Since your adapter is inner clas,, it is getting context from the activity. Those you dont see a compile error, your app will fall over at runtime when it doesnt find the view in main layout file.

Comment: Ok Thanks , so to get things clear , context.findViewById will only search for the  Element inside the layout associated with the Activity whose context is used , and in this case it fails because I need to search a different layout file?

Answer (score 5):

`findViewById()` is used to find a view in the layout of your `Activity`. This is not possible in a `Fragment` for example. `view.findViewById()` is used to find a view inside a specific other view. For example to find a view inside your `ListView` row layout. Your app crashes without it because the view you're searching for is inside `rowView`. By using the normal `findViewById()` you won't find the view.